# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'syft' (PySyft)

Tags: python, conda, pysyft

i install Pysyft using this :

---

```
conda create -n pysyft python=3
conda activate pysyft 
activate pysyft" instead "
pip install syft
```

---

and yet when i try to import the library

```
from syft.frameworks.torch.differential_privacy import pate
```

### it's show me this error :

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>         1 import numpy as np
>   ----> 2 from syft.frameworks.torch.differential_privacy import pate
>
> > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'syft'

Answer (score 4):

According to the repository import changed to:

```
from syft.frameworks.torch.dp import pate
```